# Product list in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

How can I print a list of products in `siunitx`? Is something like `\numproductlist{10x5;20x10}` possible with some modifications?

Comment: You mean, like `\numlist[parse-numbers=false]{\numproduct{10x5};\numproduct{20x10}}`?

Comment: @Mico, if possible, I would prefer a command like `\numlist` that directly takes the product expressions as a list to do the work.

Comment: Everything is doable, it's a question of if it's sensible! The reason there is not a pre-built function here is that the likelihood of a semantic link between the entries, including a need for systematic numerical processing, seems vanishingly small.

Comment: @JosephWright, agree! I was just curious if I could manage a lazy workaround for this :)